# Identification of unique observations in a partial dataframe (defined by a factor)

Tags: r

In a sample (rows) by species (columns) matrix, that contains subsets (as assigned by column Treatment):

```
data <- structure(list(S1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), S2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("S1", 
"S2", "S3", "Treatment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
9L))
```

i would like to identify those species that only occur in a given treatment.

Is that possible? Thank you very much!

/edit:

Id like to know i) the number of unique species per treatment and ii) would like to create vectors containing the species names that are unique per treatment.

Comment: Please provide your desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For species names that unique per treatment I would go with (though it could be probably optimized)

```
sapply(data[-4L], function(x) { 
  temp <- data[x == 1L, 4L]
  if(length(unique(temp)) == 1) as.character(unique(temp)) else ""
})

# S1  S2  S3 
# "" "B" "A"
```

---

For the number of unique species per treatment, here's a vectorized option

```
rowSums(!!rowsum(data[-4L], data[, 4L]))
# A B C 
# 2 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe i posted the wrong question, but your answer provides me with the amount of species found per per treatment. For example i get: $Ac_4126_4
[1] "August"   "October"  "November", so this species was found in three months (~treatment). However, my question relates to species that are _only_ found in a given treatment.

Comment: The first output gives you the observations that found in *only* one treatment. For example, `S2` is found only in treatment `B`. `S3` is found only in treatment `A`. `S1` is found in two different treatments so it gets a value of `NULL`

Comment: Just to make sure, as i am not good with the syntax, how to modify the code if the factor variable is in the nth column? just lapply(data.ap[-nL], function(x) { 
  temp <- data.ap[x == 1L, nL]
  if(!anyDuplicated(temp)) as.character(unique(temp))

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. The `rowsum(data[-4L], data[, 4L])` will give the same output as the `dplyr` option btw.

Comment: The version using sapply() is pretty much what i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarise(S1 = any(S1 == 1),
            S2 = any(S2 == 1),
            S3 = any(S3 == 1))
```

Gives you one row per treatment and one column per species.  `TRUE` indicates the species was found in that treatment.

Comment: Not sure if this adresses the question, but if so, you could simplify to: `data %>% group_by(Treatment) %>% summarise_each(funs(any(. == 1)))`

Comment: Ooo...`summarise_each`!  That's new to me, and I like it!

Comment: Don't see how that answers the question

Comment: I had interpreted the question to be how to identify which species received a treatment.  S1 and S3 both had a 1 listed somewhere within Treatment A, so they return TRUE.  But strictly speaking, without a better idea of what output nouse is hoping for, we have no idea if it answers the question or not.  It only answers my interpretation of the question.

Comment: Thank you so far. I should have been more accurate in posting the question. For starters, id like to know the number of unique species per treatment, in a second step, a histogram of observations frequencies per treatment-unique species would be nice. For now, I can easily transfer the output to excel and sort by "true".